# Unable to deploy relationship field records (JSON format) using Bulk Api

Tags: api, bulk-api

I am trying to deploy contacts from source org. to target org. using Bulk Api. I am able to deploy the records in the xml format but my requirement is to use the JSON with the relationship field records.

E.g. if I am sending contacts then it should map with the parent accounts.

Following is the code which is working with xml body.

```
//To add a batch to job
Http hAddBatch = new Http();
HttpRequest reqAddJob = new HttpRequest();
reqAddJob.setMethod('POST');
reqAddJob.setEndpoint('https://instance-api.my.salesforce.com/services/async/37.0/job/jobId/batch');
reqAddJob.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml;charset=UTF-8');
reqAddJob.setHeader('X-SFDC-Session', sessionId);
reqAddJob.setBody('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sObjects xmlns="http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload"><sObject><FirstName>Bulk Contact</FirstName><LastName>First Record</LastName><ReportsTo><sObject><Email>chandan.ppanigrahy@gmail.com</Email></sObject></ReportsTo></sObject></sObjects>');
HttpResponse resAddBatchJob = hAddBatch.send(reqAddJob);
String responseAddBatchJobString = resAddBatchJob.getBody();
System.debug('---- responseAddBatchJobString --- '+responseAddBatchJobString);
```

I am trying the JSON equivalent of the above request by changing the content type and body with:

```
reqAddJob.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
reqAddJob.setBody('[{"LastName":"[Bulk API] Chandan Contact 1 (new batch)","description":"Created from Bulk API","Contacts":{"Account":"0019000001jxxxx"}}]');//Add json values
```

Comment: How are field headers mentioned. Please add more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution..

```
//To add a batch to job
Http hAddBatch = new Http();

HttpRequest reqAddJob = new HttpRequest();

reqAddJob.setMethod('POST');

reqAddJob.setEndpoint('https://chandanlightning-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/async/37.0/job/jobId/batch');

reqAddJob.setBody('[{"LastName":"Panigrahy","Contacts":{"Email":"sfdc@salesforce.com"}}]');//Add json values

HttpResponse resAddBatchJob = hAddBatch.send(reqAddJob);

String responseAddBatchJobString = resAddBatchJob.getBody();
```

We should provide the relationship name and an indexed field to map to the target org. in the request JSON.